# react-native - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am struggling with the `React Native` and `aws-sdk`. The reason I use `aws-sdk` instead of `aws-amplify` is because:

[aws-amplify does not support Using a pre-signed URL to upload a file](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1687)

My project is working fine until `aws-sdk` is installed by `npm` and `aws-sdk-react-native` is imported (this file is 4.3MB when `aws-sdk` version is "2.369.0").

After adding this line of code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native");
```

The application crashes with the error message:

```
transform[stdout]: <--- Last few GCs --->
transform[stdout]:
transform[stdout]: [5433:0x103800000]    59176 ms: Mark-sweep 1256.2 (1442.0) -> 1236.2 (1434.5) MB, 3855.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.239, current mu = 0.130) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
transform[stdout]: [5433:0x103800000]    63390 ms: Mark-sweep 1259.8 (1442.5) -> 1243.1 (1438.5) MB, 3924.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.161, current mu = 0.069) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
transform[stdout]:
transform[stdout]:
transform[stdout]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
transform[stdout]:
transform[stdout]: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
transform[stdout]:
transform[stdout]:     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1e49a5a5be3d]
transform[stdout]: Security context: 0x21d5cac9e6e1 <JSObject>
transform[stdout]:     1: queue [0x21d5c3f5fc09] [/Users/yumac/Projects/ReactNative/Demo/OutOfMemory/node_modules/@babel/generator/lib/buffer.js:~88] [pc=0x1e49a5f9825e](this=0x21d55e682309 <Buffer map = 0x21d51ca6ba29>,str=0x21d577355491 <String[12]:             >)
transform[stdout]:     2: StringLiteral [0x21d5c3f07491] [/Users/yumac/Projects/ReactNative/Demo/OutOfMemory/node_modules/@babel/ge...
transform[stdout]:
transform[stderr]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
transform[stderr]:  1: 0x10003ae75 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  2: 0x10003b07f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  3: 0x1001a7ae5 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  4: 0x100572ef2 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  5: 0x1005759c5 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  6: 0x10057186f v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  7: 0x10056fa44 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  8: 0x10057c2dc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]:  9: 0x10057c35f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 10: 0x10054bca4 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 11: 0x1007d3b54 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
transform[stderr]: 12: 0x1e49a5a5be3d
transform[stderr]: 13: 0x1e49a5f9825e
transform[stderr]: 14: 0x1e49a5f84e0f
transform[stderr]: 15: 0x1e49a5a0a5c3
transform[stderr]: 16: 0x1e49a5ee8a79
```

I try a lot of solution like:

[increase-memory-limit](https://github.com/endel/increase-memory-limit)

[node --max-old-space-size=8192 index.js](https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c)

If you tried these solution and it is work, please let me know. Maybe I did something wrong

If you have any suggestion, I am always willing to hear from you.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I am able to run debug by changing the `package.json` to:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
  "start-max": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    ...
},
```

In terminal run: "npm run start-max" to start the node server with 8,192 MB.
Then run your project as normal: "react-native run-android".

## Android release:

Inside the app build.gradle file, add this line

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node", "--max-old-space-size=8192"]
]
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @LuongTruong answer with iOS fixes.

## **iOS Release:**

Go to (*XCode Workspace -> Project -> Build Phases -> Bundle React Native code and images*)

The command should have those three lines at the top

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
export NODE_ARGS=--max-old-space-size=8192
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
```

Reference at https://sandny.com/2019/12/30/react-native-heap-limit-allocation-failed/